# Kendo UI Angular 2 Grid Excel Export

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm trying to add excel export functionality to Kendo UI angular 2 grid, but getting an error while the angular 2 app loads:

```
Can't bind to 'toolbar' since it isn't a known property of 'kendo-grid'.
```

Here is the code snippet I'm using:

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridView" [height]="700" [pageSize]="pageSize"
                        [toolbar]="['excel']" 
                        [excel]="{fileName: 'Reprocessingdetails.xlsx'}"
                        [skip]="skip"
                          [pageable]="{
                            info: true,
                            type: 'input',
                            pageSizes: false,
                            previousNext: true
                          }"
                          [scrollable]="'none'"
                          (pageChange)="pageChange($event)"
                          [sortable]="{ mode: 'single', allowUnsort: true }"
                          [sort]="sort"
                          (sortChange)="reprocessingResultsSortChange($event)"
                        >
                <kendo-grid-column field="isSelected" title="Select">
                    <template kendoCellTemplate let-dataItem>
                        <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="dataItem.isSelected" />
                    </template>
                </kendo-grid-column>
                <kendo-grid-column field="reprocessingType" title="Reprocessing Type">
                </kendo-grid-column>


            </kendo-grid>
```

Excel export functionality wasn't mentioned in the roadmap, so is it fair to assume it is already present? If so, how do I make the above snippet work? any help?

Answer (score 2):

[Excel Export](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/excel-export/) is now an official feature of the Kendo UI Grid. It can also be used on its own, as [a non-visual component](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/excelexport/) for generating XLSX files.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the Kendo UI Grid for Angular 2 does not support Excel export. The toolbar is set via `ToolbarComponent`, which currently projects the content using `ng-content`. You can see all this in the [docs](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/ToolbarComponent/)

Comment: Hi @knikolov, Thanks for confirming. Will this be included in Jan 2017 update? I'm currently working on a migration project which requires these features to be carried over from previous Silverlight based solution. (Column menus (filtering and column chooser) and export functionality)

Comment: It is not planned for the Jan release.

Comment: All of the mentioned features are tentatively planned for completion by May 2017. We release frequently so keep an eye on the changelog over here http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/changelog/

Answer (score 0):

Excel export feature has been added (use the kendoGridExcelCommand) and an example can be seen [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/export/excel-export/).